# Dynamic parogramming

Tags: java, dynamic

There are N streets in a town and in each street there is one treasure house with certain number of gold coins - C(1) .... C(N) in it. As the robber is intelligent, in order not to get caught, if he robs in a house in a given street he does not rob in the houses in the two streets which are adjacent to the house robbed (either to it's left or right). Thus he avoids awareness among the people and his risk is reduced. Given N and the coins C(i) (where i= 1 to N) in each of the treasure house, find the maximum gold coins M, that the robber can acquire.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MaximiseRobbery {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  int houses = scan.nextInt();
  int[] amPerHouse = new int[houses];
  for (int i = 0; i < houses; i++) {
   amPerHouse[i] = scan.nextInt();
  }
  int maximumRobbery = maximizeRobbery(amPerHouse, houses);
  System.out.println(maximumRobbery);
  scan.close();
 }

 private static int maximizeRobbery(int[] amPerHouse, int houses) {
  if (houses == 1) {
   return amPerHouse[0];
  } else if (houses == 2) {
   return Math.max(amPerHouse[0], amPerHouse[1]);
  }
  int[] dp = new int[amPerHouse.length];
  dp[0] = amPerHouse[0];
  dp[1] = amPerHouse[1];
  for (int i = 2; i < houses; i++) {
   dp[i] = Math.max(dp[i - 2] + amPerHouse[i], dp[i - 1]);
  }
  return dp[houses - 1];
 }
}
```

for input:

```
7
10 20 15 1 9 12 5
```

output:

```
32
```

but according to the above implementation the output obtained is 39

also for input:

```
10
5 6 6 16 30 15 13 16 19 27
```

output:

```
63
```

but according to the above implementation the output obtained is 84

Comment: What have you tried?  Why do you want us to do your homework?

Comment: Are you sure that the problem statement is correct?

Comment: The boundary condition might be incorrect - it appears the code can select the second adjacent house when it should be minimally the third adjacent house.

Comment: @AndrewS That's what I thought and answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you didn't understand the statement correctly. What it says, IMO, is that if you rob the house on street `i` you can't rob the houses on the 2 streets on the left, so `i-1` and `i-2`, and on the 2 streets on the right, so `i+1` and `i+2`. Modifying according to this should make it work. Indeed in the first example the robbed houses are on indexes `1` and `5`, so `sum = 20 + 12 = 32`.

Comment: Thought so tk u